# Remove front from WordPress default taxonomy permalink structure

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, taxonomy

In WordPress,

I have the permalink structure like so:

```
example.com/blog/%postname%/
```

Which is what I want for my blog and posts, but this creates the default taxonomy permalink structure to be:

```
example.com/blog/category/slug-here/
example.com/blog/tag/slug-here/
```

Instead I need it to be without the front ('**blog**'), e.g.

```
example.com/category/slug-here/
example.com/tag/slug-here/
```

I'm using the default categories and tags on custom post types too, so I don't want the permalink to include the '/blog/' base.

Is this just a matter of setting with_front to false somehow for categories and tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer.

In WordPress settings, under permalinks.

When the category and tag base are empty they are set to a default structure, just add 'category' in the category base and 'tag' in the tag base.